# FxCop and Teamcity: Doesn't show code or code-lines

Tags: teamcity, fxcop, teamcity-5.1

I am trying to use the FxCop build runner in TeamCity (5.1.2) and while I get the analysis output, the errors all show '0' for the code line link and I can't open anything in the IDE using that link.

I am assuming (since I have not been able to get any further) that I should be able to see the offending lines of code.

Currently, I have setup the FxCop build as a dependency on the normal build.  It takes the artifacts which contain all of the output in /bin/Release (dll, pdb, exe, etc) and extracts them before running.  I am running using an FxCop project file that was created.

Has anyone else had success with the FxCop build runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FxCop uses the information in PDB files to provide the source context line numbers.  Are you sure that the PDB files are actually present in the same location(s) as the copies of your assemblies that are being analyzed by FxCop?

Comment: You're right, it is working now.  I had fixed this but it looks like the last build a ran didn't grab the latest artifact zip file.  Re-running it finally produced the proper result.